# Fundamental set of solutions for First Order Differential Equation

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am a bit unsure about this question and how to approach it and have tried numerous times. It is as follows:

$$\overrightarrow{y_1}(t) = \begin{pmatrix} 2e^{3t}-4e^{-t}\\ 3e^{3t}-10e^{-t}\end{pmatrix} . \\\overrightarrow{y_2}(t) = \begin{pmatrix} 8e^{3t} + 2e^{-t} \\ 12e^{3t} + 5e^{-t} \end{pmatrix} $$

form a fundamental set (i.e., linearly independent set) of solutions for the initial value problem

$$\overrightarrow{y'} = \begin{pmatrix} 9 & -4 \\ 15 & -7  \end{pmatrix} \overrightarrow{y}$$ where $$\overrightarrow{y}(0) = \begin{pmatrix} 36 \\ 54 \end{pmatrix}$$

impose the given initial condition and find the unique solution to the initial value problem
$$\overrightarrow{y}(t) = (\qquad )\begin{pmatrix}2e^{3t} - 4e^{-t} \\ 3e^{3t} - 10e^{-t} \end{pmatrix} + (\qquad)\begin{pmatrix} 8e^{3t}+2e^{-t} \\ 12e^{3t} + 5e^{-t} \end{pmatrix}$$

Any help would be nice. Thank you. I tried to plug in and solve for the matrix $$\overrightarrow{y'} = \begin{pmatrix} 9 & -4 \\ 15 & -7  \end{pmatrix} \overrightarrow{y}$$ by finding its eigenvalues and eigenvectors but was ineffective. Advice would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The brackets you left empty can be labeled $ c_1 $ and $ c_2 $, respectively.

Now you have two sets of linear equations with two unknowns, $ c_1 $ and $ c_2 $. Using the initial condition removes $ t $ from the equations.

It seems like you've tried this already, you just haven't used the fact that each vector is multiplied by these constants:

$$\overrightarrow{y}(0) = \begin{pmatrix} c_1 && c_2 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}-2 \\ -7 \end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix} c_1 && c_2 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 10 \\ 17 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}36 \\ 54\end{pmatrix}$$

The initial condition fixes these two unknowns to a unique value. Remember that the general solution is:

$ \vec{y}(t) = c_1 \vec{y_1}(t) + c_2 \vec{y_2}(t) $

Comment: I got it now, thank you for the help !